# JS replace not working on string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to replace all instances of # in a string with a variable. It's not working but not retuning any error either.

```
answer_form = '<textarea name="answer_#" rows="5"></textarea>'+
              '<input type="file" name="img_#" />';

question_num = 5;

answer_form.replace(/#/g, question_num);
```

The hashes remain.

Not sure what I'm missing?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

`.replace()` returns a new string (it does not modify the existing string) so you would need:

```
answer_form = answer_form.replace(/#/g, question_num);
```

You probably should also make `question_num` a string though auto type conversions probably handle that for you.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4cAz5/

FYI, in Javascript, strings are immutable - an existing string is never modified.  So any method which makes a modification to the string (like `concat`, `replace`, `slice`, `substr`, `substring`, `toLowerCase`, `toUpperCase`, etc...) ALWAYS returns a new string.

Comment: `.splice()` is an exception. It modifies the string, as well as returns the substring.

Comment: @ShubhamKushwah - I think you're confused here.  There is no `.splice()` method for strings (it is available for arrays).

Comment: You're right @jfriend00 - I was in the mindset that if `.slice()` is there, then `.splice()` would be too. Glad to know.

Answer (score 10):

Your code is correct. Just add the value to the variable like this:

```
answer_form = '<textarea name="answer_#" rows="5"></textarea>'+
              '<input type="file" name="img_#" />';

question_num = 5;

answer_form = answer_form.replace(/#/g, question_num);
```