# JS replacing all occurrences of string using variable

Tags: javascript, string, variables, replace

I know that `str.replace(/x/g, "y")`replaces all x's in the string but I want to do this

```
function name(str,replaceWhat,replaceTo){
    str.replace(/replaceWhat/g,replaceTo);
}
```

How can i use a variable in the first argument?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `RegExp` constructor takes a string and creates a regular expression out of it.

```
function name(str,replaceWhat,replaceTo){
    var re = new RegExp(replaceWhat, 'g');
    return str.replace(re,replaceTo);
}
```

If `replaceWhat` might contain characters that are special in regular expressions, you can do:

```
function name(str,replaceWhat,replaceTo){
    replaceWhat = replaceWhat.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    var re = new RegExp(replaceWhat, 'g');
    return str.replace(re,replaceTo);
}
```

See [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Comment: This doesn't work as expected if replaceWhat contains regexp metacharacters, e.g. `*`, `+`, `[`.

Comment: @pts So does a literal regexp.

Comment: Then add this logic in as well: [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Comment: If used like the asker intended, this will give wrong results if metacharacters appear in replaceWhat. So better chose another answer!

Comment: @dronus Isn't that what pts said in his comment? dc5 pointed to a workaround for that.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what pts said. But that doesn't make the answer itself valid... maybe you like to edit it?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringinject

Comment: remember, you need to bind this to a new variable : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231644/js-replace-not-working-on-string?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @thatOneGuy Good catch, I've added a `return` to the functions. I was obviously focused on the regexp part, not the replace part.

Answer (score 0):

**The third parameter of flags below was removed from browsers a few years ago and this answer is no longer needed -- now replace works global without flags**

---

Replace has an alternate form that takes 3 parameters and accepts a string:

```
function name(str,replaceWhat,replaceTo){
    str.replace(replaceWhat,replaceTo,"g");
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: This is Firefox-specific, in Chrome it replaces only the first occurrence.

Comment: True... it had the "nonstandard" flag.

Comment: remember, you need to bind this to a new variable : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231644/js-replace-not-working-on-string?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Hogan this is not working currently please remove this answer or update with working solution.