# Create text and change text on click in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementById("p").textContent += "You are now connected;"


function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("p").textContent.replace("You are now connected;", "You are disconnected");
}
```

```html
<p id ="p"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">out</button>
```

I created some text using Javascript and now I want to change the content of the text after I press a button but I am having difficulties with it.

Comment: Duplicate of [JS replace not working on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231644/js-replace-not-working-on-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work since `replace` does not modify the original value, but instead returns the result. You can fix the code by instead assigning `element.textContent` to the result of `replace`.

```
function myFunction() {
   const element = document.getElementById("p")
   element.textContent = element.textContent.replace("You are now connected;", "You are disconnected");
}
```

In this example though there really is no point in using `replace`, instead of just assigning the new value.

```
function myFunction() {
   const element = document.getElementById("p")
   element.textContent = "You are disconnected";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) doesn't perform the operation "in-place", it returns the string. Set the `textContent` to the result of the operation:

```js
document.getElementById("p").textContent += "You are now connected;"


function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("p").textContent = document.getElementById("p").textContent.replace("You are now connected;", "You are disconnected");
}
```

```html
<p id ="p"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">out</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`replace` creates a new string but you are not assigning it to your element. You need to assign it.

```js
document.getElementById("p").textContent += "You are now connected;"


function myFunction() {
  let p = document.getElementById("p");  
  p.textContent = p.textContent.replace("You are now connected;", "You are disconnected");
}
```

```html
<p id ="p"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">out</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("p").innerText += "You are now connected;"


function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("p").innerText = "You are disconnected";
}
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">out</button>
```